# Android Intent choose CSV for import

Tags: android, file, csv, android-intent

I want to import a specific CSV file into the database. I'm using the library aFileChooser to choose the file, but the data in the CSV file are not imported. Where am I wrong? thanks

```
@Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch(requestCode) {


     case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1: {
           if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               Uri uri = data.getData();
                File file1 = com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getFile(uri);
                proImportCSV(file1);
            }
          }
      }
    }



ricevi_csv= (Button) findViewById(R.id.but_ricevi_csv);
    ricevi_csv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

         Intent chooseFile;
          Intent intent;
          chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          chooseFile.setType("application/image");
            intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a CSV");
            startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1);
          }
        });
    }


private void proImportCSV(File from){

 File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 File exportDir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath());
 File csvFile = new File(exportDir, getString(R.string.app_name)+".csv");

  try {
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
// reading CSV and writing table
CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
String[] vv = null;
while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
   cv.clear();
   SimpleDateFormat currFormater  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
   SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

      String eDDte;
        try {
            Date nDate = currFormater.parse(vv[0]);
            eDDte = postFormater.format(nDate);
            cv.put(Table.DATA,eDDte);
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
        }
 cv.put(Table.C,vv[1]);
 cv.put(Table.E,vv[2]);
 cv.put(Table.U,vv[3]);
 cv.put(Table.C,vv[4]);
 SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  db.insert(Table.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
```

}
dataRead.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("TAG",e.toString());

}

Comment: Are you getting any Exceptions? The only weird thing I can see is you're getting "application/image", as opposed to using "text/csv" and Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT instead of Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE. You may even want to use "new File(data.getData().getPath())" instead of "com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.utils.FileUtils.getFile(uri);" -- I just did this CSV important stuff yesterday and that seemed to work properly for me. Your reading stuff looks ok, although you may want to call dataRead.readNext() before entering your while loop to make sure you skip the header line (if you have one)

Comment: Can you show me your code?  `Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE ` not working for me

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as an answer. Just give me a sec to pull it from github

Comment: And I was mistaken about removing ACTION_GET_CONTENT btw

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the intent using the type "text/csv" and a Category of CATEGORY_OPENABLE:

```
private void selectCSVFile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("text/csv");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open CSV"), ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1);
}
```

Now in your onActivityResult:

```
case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1: {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            proImportCSV(new File(data.getData().getPath());
        }
      }
  }
```

And now we need to change your proImportCSV method to use the actual File we're passing back:

```
private void proImportCSV(File from){
  try {
    // Delete everything above here since we're reading from the File we already have
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    // reading CSV and writing table
    CSVReader dataRead = new CSVReader(new FileReader(from)); // <--- This line is key, and why it was reading the wrong file

    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase(); // LEt's just put this here since you'll probably be using it a lot more than once
    String[] vv = null;
    while((vv = dataRead.readNext())!=null) {
       cv.clear();
       SimpleDateFormat currFormater  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
       SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

       String eDDte;
        try {
            Date nDate = currFormater.parse(vv[0]);
            eDDte = postFormater.format(nDate);
            cv.put(Table.DATA,eDDte);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
         cv.put(Table.C,vv[1]);
         cv.put(Table.E,vv[2]);
         cv.put(Table.U,vv[3]);
         cv.put(Table.C,vv[4]);
          db.insert(Table.TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    } dataRead.close();

    } catch (Exception e) { Log.e("TAG",e.toString());

    }
}
```

Comment: intent.setType("text/csv"); does not work on regular file explorers, i can pick any file from them. But it does have effect on Dropbox app, which only shows .csv files. How to do same for regular file explorers?

Comment: Try intent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer is perfect, but you need to change two things.

Open the intent using the type "*/*", as file manager in android doesn't let pick csv files if we use "text/csv":

```
private void selectCSVFile(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open CSV"),             ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1);
}
```

Now in your onActivityResult trim the file path, as file path contain garbage path before storage or /storage. So you need to delete those characters to make your csv reader find the path:

```
case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE1: {
       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            proImportCSV(new File(data.getData().getPath().substring(15));
        }
      }
  }
```

[more on file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483156/file-path-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

```
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                intent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CREATE_FILE);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I collected all possible answers:

1- Base on MIME types: `intent.setType("text/csv");` for **SDK_INT <= 25**

2- `intent.setType("text/*");` show all Text formats

3- `intent.setType("*/*");` show all formats  @Towsif Ahamed Labib

4- i`ntent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");` @tabina

But these below types don't work:

`intent.setType("*/.csv");`

`intent.setType("text");`

`intent.setType("aplication/csv");`

`intent.setType("text/*cvs");`