# Selecting a csv file from storage in android

Tags: android, csv

Hello I wish to upload a csv file in android but somehow this code segment doesn't work for csv file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/csv");
startActivityForResult(intent, OPEN_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: What do you mean by code segment doesn't work. Is it throwing an error (if so post it) or is it not doing anything? Please add some details

Comment: Your code is not for uploading a csv file but only to let the user select one. Please edit your post as you wrote it pretty confusing. Change the subject to begin with.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't even let the user select the csv file. I think thats my exact problem

Comment: Yes. Indeed. Thats all. So you should change the subject and edit your post so it reflects your problem. Again: your problem has nothing to do with uploading.

Comment: I have changed it. is there any solution you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use ACTION_GET_CONTENT instead of ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, and you'll need to add CATEGORY_OPENABLE to the Intent.

See the selected answer at [Android Intent choose CSV for import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664193/android-intent-choose-csv-for-import)