# Upload to parse csv file

Tags: android, android-intent

Do Android have any way to browse and pick csv file from SD card using intents?
I Have tried:

```
Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
mediaIntent.setType("text/comma-separated-values/csv");
startActivityForResult(mediaIntent, REQUEST_CODE_CSV);
```

but it let me choose any type of file & returns path of selected file. I want to **restrict user to choose only csv file** (ie show only csv file & no other file in file browser).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664193/android-intent-choose-csv-for-import

Comment: @WaelDalloul It may seen to be duplicate, but I have clearly stated that " it let me choose any type of file "  & accepted answer of the provided link also does the same.

Answer (score 1):

Set MIME type for the intent this will change the behavior of share intent.

```
    Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    mediaIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    mediaIntent.setType("text/csv");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(mediaIntent, "CSV FILE"), REQUEST_CODE_CSV);
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that file chooser allows to choose any type of file. This code does the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                     "Report.pdf");
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent pdfOpenintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
pdfOpenintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
pdfOpenintent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
try {
    startActivity(pdfOpenintent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

}
```