# File path in Android studio

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send email with attachment and everything works okay apart attaching file.

When calling method, it says: java.io.FileNotFoundException

Although I manually insert exact path:
 file/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.admin.mailsender/files/test.xls

I haven't actually declared anywhere from where that function should look, but isn't providing that path enough?

```
    private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = "test@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Test";
        String message = "Test - body";
        String filePath = "file/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.admin.mailsender/files/test.xls";


        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message, filePath );

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.admin.mailsender/files/test.xls
```

This is not a path on Android. At best, this might be a valid path:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.admin.mailsender/files/test.xls
```

Whether that is the correct path will vary by device and user. For short-term testing on your own device, you're welcome to play with hard-coding paths like this, but in general you should be using methods to derive paths. In this case, that would be:

```
new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), "test.xls")
```

...where `context` is some `Context` (your `Activity`, the `Application` singleton, etc.).

Comment: But how can I pull string path, that I can pass to method, from that new File(context.GetExternalFilesDir(null), "test.xls") ?

Comment: @Kertix: Well, ideally, you would pass a `File` object to the method, if it is your method that you control. If you are calling some library API that needs a string path, call `getAbsolutePath()` on the `File` object.

Comment: It is sent by Javamail api. But that getAbsolutePath() worked like a charm. Have been battling with that hours. Major thanks for spending that time.

Comment: JavaMail accepts a File argument in the [MimeBodyPart.attachFile method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#attachFile-java.io.File-).